# How to pass a dictionary as a parameter and then unpack it as variables in the function using it?

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters

I'm trying to pass some parameters to a function and I'm thinking of the best way of doing it. Since there's 32 variables that I want to pass, I wouldn't like to do it manually such as

```
def myfunction(var1,var2,var3...etc)
```

so basically what I have is something like this:

```
def variables():
  dict = {var1:'value1', var2:'value2', var3:'value3'...var32:'value32'}
  return dict

def myfunction(*args):
  print(args)

def main():
  variables_in_dict = variables()
  myfunction(variables_in_dict)
```

`print(args)` returns the variable names as in

```
('var1','var2','var3'....'var32')
```

My desired output will be something where I could do
`print(var1)` and get `value1`, as in already having the dictionary keys as variables and the values assigned to those variables.

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `print(var1)`, how about this:

```
def myfunction(var1, var2, var3, **kwargs):
    print(var1)

def main():
    variables_in_dict = variables()
    myfunction(**variables_in_dict)
```

If the super set of parameter names is fixed, you can do the following. If some of them can be omitted, you can assign them default values.

```
def myfunction(var1, var2, var3, ..., var32):
```

Also, usually not recommended but as another possibility, you can use `exec`.

```
def myfunction(**kwargs):
    for kwarg in kwargs:
        exec("{} = '{}'".format(kwarg, kwargs[kwarg]), globals())
    print(var1)
    print(var2)
```

This programmatically generates string *code* to interpret, e.g., `"var1 = 'value1'"`, then `exec`ute it. So `var1` is programmatically declared and initialized.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want only to `print(var1)`, I would like to be able to print any single variable from the 32 possible, if that makes sense

Comment: @rekeson21 You can add more arguments; `myfunction(var1, var2, ..., var32)`. Or, you can use `exec`.

Comment: @rekeson21 Edited. Please check it. :)

Comment: The exec method worked with what I was expecting to do, thank you for your answer. Even though I know it's not recommended, I think it was the easiest way to approach this scenario.

Comment: Yes it does the job, as you know it is not recommended, if you try to declare new variable and if that is already present in the dictionary then it would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using ** instead of *

```
def variables():
    dictVal = {'var1': 'value1', 'var2': 'value2', 'var3': 'value3'}
    return dictVal


def myfunction(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['var1'])


variables_in_dict = variables()
myfunction(**variables_in_dict)
```

Comment: When I do `print(kwargs)` I get the whole dictionary printed, my intent is to use every key-value pair in the dictionary as a variable with their corresponding value

Comment: In this situation I would prefer to directly access from dictionary print(kwargs['var1']) rather than declaring them as new variables. It saves data redundancy and corruption.